# How to add dictionary line to an JSON file

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to achieve the below JSON format and store it in a json file:

```
{
    "Name": "Anurag",
    "resetRecordedDate": false,
    "ED": {
        "Link": "google.com"
    }
}
```

I know how to create a simple JSON file using JSON dumps but not really sure how to add something similar to a dictionary for one of the records within the JSON file.

Comment: Do you want to add keys to an existing dictionary and dump it into json file? Or read from json and append to it then dump it back?

Comment: I want to read from JSON and append to it and then dump back using  python or pandas @LeelaPrasad

Comment: Do:  1) Load the JSON from file 2) `my_dict['new_key'] = 'new_value'` 3) Dump the dict to a file

Comment: What if the value of ED is passed from a csv file. Can I add csv.DictReader(csvfile) file directly against the ED key?  @balderman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the input json content is

```
  {
        "Name": "Anurag",
        "resetRecordedDate": False
    }
```

Program

```
import json

# read file
with open('example.json', 'r') as infile:
    data=infile.read()

# parse file
parsed_json = json.loads(data)

# Add dictionary element
parsed_json["ED"] = {
        "Link": "google.com"
    }

# print(json.dumps(parsed_json, indent=4))

# write to json
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(parsed_json, outfile)
```

o/p

```
{ 
    "Name": "Anurag", 
    "resetRecordedDate": false, 
    "ED": { 
                     "Link": "google.com"
      }
 }
```

Comment: What if the value of ED is passed from a csv file. Can I add csv.DictReader(csvfile) file directly against the ED key?

Comment: As long as its a valid dictionary, yes you can. So that your json dumps doesn't end up creating a weird json or fail to even do so.

Comment: I am getting a type error while parsing csv.dictreader
```
csvfile = open('formatted.csv', 'r')

dictionary ={
"Name": "Anurag",
"resetRecordedDate": "false",
}
# Serializing json  
json_object = json.dumps(dictionary, indent = 4) 
  
# Writing to sample.json 
with open("sample.json", "w") as outfile: 
  outfile.write(json_object) 



# read file
with open('sample.json', 'r') as infile:
    data=infile.read()

# parse file
parsed_json = json.loads(data)

# Add dictionary element
parsed_json["embeddedData"] = {
        csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    }
```
@LeelaPrasad

Comment: Object of type set is not serializable